# Does AFNetworking support HTTP2 now?

Tags: afnetworking-2, http2

Since IOS9 and OS X 10.11 has already support HTTP2, can I using it in using AFNetworking now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After an experiment, I see that APIs based on `NSURLConnection` won't using HTTP2, APIs based on `NSURLSession` can make HTTP2 requests on iOS9.